# How to make a navbar horizontal with Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I wonder how I make my navbar horizontal with Bootstrap? I don't know where in my code I should write the different commands. I'm totally new to this (if you couldn't tell that already.. So be kind and over pedagogic please :)

[image]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

I think the default bootstrap example on their website is already horizontal, take a look here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/
if I am not understanding your question correctly, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

I have used the below before to produce a horizontal navbar. This is however using Bootstrap 4.5.3 so there might be some differences, but hopefully this would be a good starting point. Note that the below is within `nav` instead of within `header` as you currently have.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light border">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Your Title on Navbar</a>
    <button aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=#>Your Nav Link on Left 1</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=#>Your Nav Link on Left 2</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=#>Your Nav Link on Left 3</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href=#>Your Nav Link on RightLog Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```